# How do you prevent "unhashable type 'list'"?

Tags: python, 2d, replit

So, I was making a simple 2D game in pygame, and was making the map (following a tutorial video, don't judge me, I'm new to pygame) and using replit.com, and that error showed up in the console.

here's my code for it:

```
import pygame, sys
W = 0
S = 1
G = 2
F = 3

BLUE = (0,0,255)
SAND = (194,176,128)
GRASS = (124,252,0)
FOREST = (0,100,0)

TileColor = {W : BLUE,
            S : SAND,
            G : GRASS,
            F : FOREST
            }

map1 = {(W, S, G, F, F, F, G, S, W, W, W, W),
       [W, S, S, G, G, G, G, F, F, W, W, W],
       [W, S, G, G, G, F, F, F, F, F, W, W],
       [W, S, S, G, G, G, G, G, F, F, F, W]
       }

TILESIZE = 40
MAPWIDTH = 12
MAPHEIGHT = 4

pygame.init()
DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode((MAPWIDTH * TILESIZE,MAPHEIGHT * TILESIZE))

while True:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      pygame.quit()
      sys.exit()

  for row in range(MAPHEIGHT):
    for col in range(MAPWIDTH):
      pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY,TileColor[map1[row][col]],(col * TILESIZE,row * TILESIZE,TILESIZE,TILESIZE))
  
  pygame.display.update
```

if anyone has any suggestions for changing my code, please say, and I am sticking with replit.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty much correct already.  I'm just guessing at how your code is supposed to work, but using a python dictionary for the tile colours with integer-variables as keys is what's causing the issue.

If you change your tile keys to a letter:

```
TileColor = { 'W' : BLUE,
              'S' : SAND,
              'G' : GRASS,
              'F' : FOREST }
```

And then in your map, use letters too:

```
map1 = [ "WSGFFFGSWWWW",
         "WSSGGGGFFWWW",
         "WSGGGFFFFFWW",
         "WSSGGGGGFFFW" ]
```

It works pretty much perfectly:

[image: screen shot]

Full code:

```
import pygame, sys

BLUE = (0,0,255)
SAND = (194,176,128)
GRASS = (124,252,0)
FOREST = (0,100,0)

TileColor = {'W' : BLUE,
             'S' : SAND,
             'G' : GRASS,
             'F' : FOREST }

map1 = [ "WSGFFFGSWWWW",
         "WSSGGGGFFWWW",
         "WSGGGFFFFFWW",
         "WSSGGGGGFFFW" ]

TILESIZE = 40
MAPWIDTH = 12
MAPHEIGHT = 4

pygame.init()
DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode((MAPWIDTH * TILESIZE,MAPHEIGHT * TILESIZE))

while True:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      pygame.quit()
      sys.exit()

  for row in range(MAPHEIGHT):
    for col in range(MAPWIDTH):
      pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY,TileColor[map1[row][col]],(col * TILESIZE,row * TILESIZE,TILESIZE,TILESIZE))
  
  pygame.display.update()
```